# SAXParser sometimes give me back a bad value

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

This is weird..

I've a DefaultHandler that is actually handling everything well but sometimes, for no apparent reasons, it will give me 0 instead of the correct value. This is happening everytime in the same place so there is something wrong but I cannot figure out what!

The problem is this. I'm parsing a time like "17:00:00". When the parser arrive at the "strange time" it will parse it like this -> "17:00:0", call one more time the method characters(char[] ch, int start, int end), and parse the last "0".

WTF?

Pratically it will set the end to 7 instead of 8. And this is working for everything except for a few values!

The code is pretty straightforward, it's just a simple saxparser. This is the characters method:

```
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int end) {
    if(on_element)
        value = new String(ch, start, end);
    }
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `characters` method can be called more than once for the text within a single pair of open and close tags.

Your code assumes it's only called once, which will frequently be true for small data, but not always.

You need to initialize a buffer in the `startElement` method for that tag, collect into the buffer in the `characters` method, and convert the buffer to a string in the `endElement`.

My answer to [this question where the user was making the same mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855421/android-sax-parsing-returns-null-values-and-retrieve-values-in-tags-of-same-nam/5855796#5855796) contains some code doing this to correct more complete code that user had posted.  Reading that may help you with your code.

Comment: Oh, great. This seems a good solution! Sorry to bother you, can you provide me a snippet?

Comment: @Enrichman - see my edit, and look at the code in my answer to the linked question.  If you post more of your handler, I could update with modified code, but you may be able to do it yourself based on the code in the other.

Comment: It was very clear! Now everything works! Thanks! I really thought that that method would be called once but I was wrong. Lucky me to find the SAXParser expert online!! ;D